# Nodejs throwing a EPROTO error on a GET call to a secured endpoint

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am making a get call to an endpoint and getting an error.

```
Error: write EPROTO 140041198368576:error:140943F2:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert 

unexpected message:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1543:SSL alert number 10\n
```

I am using request-promise. But, I tried with node-fetch, Axios, request-promise-native, and even native http and https module and still getting the same error. Also, I have tried it on node versions 10.x and 12.x still failing. The error is intermittent and doesn't always fail.

Comment: This is a bug, either in OpenSSL or the server you are connecting to. Best start would be to find out from the server (i.e. logs) what it thinks the problem is. Failing that, if 'intermittent' is not TOO rare, get a network capture (tcpdump, wireshark, or similar) containing the problem and manually determine if the messages sent are actually wrong (OpenSSL bug) or actually correct and the server is wrong to reject (server bug). Go from there. Except on Windows, nodejs normally uses the system-supplied OpenSSL, which will be the same regardless of nodejs version.

Comment: The server is using TLS1.0,1.1,1.2. Before it was using SSL2.0 and it was working fine but with TLS it's breaking.

Comment: SSL 2 (SSL did not use 'point' numbers) has been completely broken and prohibited for use for over 20 years -- how old is this server? You certainly won't find any up to date software anywhere that supports it. (SSL 3 is also broken, but it is sufficiently similar to the first versions of TLS that a _few_ implementations still support it.) In any case that does nothing to help fix your problem.

Comment: The server although new, was previously using SSL2 they have discontinued it now. Also, adding https agent somehow solved the problem 
   const agentOptions = {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    };

    const agent = new https.Agent(agentOptions);

Answer (score 0):

Adding This somehow solved the problem

```
const agentOptions = {
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

const agent = new https.Agent(agentOptions);

const options = {
  uri: targetURL,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + token,
  },
  agent: agent,
  json: true
};
```